# как сделать появление плавно блока при прокрутке вверх?jQuery

Tags: jquery

вот  как тут https://www.olx.ua/ черный блок верхний

```
<div class="site-header sticky">
</div>
```

спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для достижения этого эффекта можно использовать CSS переходы (так это реализовано на указанном Вами ресурсе), либо воспользоваться средствами анимации jQuery.
Также необходимо создать обработчик события прокрутки страницы.
Блок с заголовком фиксируем (position: fixed).

CSS

```
body {
    height: 2000px /* чтобы было, что прокручивать */
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8);
}

.hidden-header {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
```

Javascript

```
var headerVisible = true;
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    
    if(headerVisible && scrollTop > scrollPos)
    {
        headerVisible = false;
        $("#header").addClass('hidden-header');
    }
    else if(!headerVisible && scrollTop < scrollPos)
    {
        headerVisible = true;
        $("#header").removeClass('hidden-header');
    }
    
    scrollPos = scrollTop;
});
```

Можно добавить задержку при помощи таймера.

https://jsfiddle.net/0utabnx7/

Comment: Хорошее решение (+). И кстати, лучше пользоваться встроенным сниппетом, открывается на **Ctrl+M**

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.